# django add form dynamically inside div innerhtml

Tags: django, django-templates, innerhtml, django-forms

I'm new to Django and trying to insert a form dynamically using javascript within a div. However nothing seems to be working when I try to add the form tag. I have looked at [Django, Javascript: Form injected into DOM via javascript innerHtml crashes google chrome tab on submit. Works in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363111/django-javascript-form-injected-into-dom-via-javascript-innerhtml-crashes-goog) but that won't solve my problem. 
Below is the function where I'm trying to insert the form tag. How can this be achieved correctly?

```
function createForms() 
{
    divForForms = document.getElementById("formsToAdd");
    divForForms.innerHTML = "";
    for(var ch = 1; ch <= chboxes; ch++) {
        var formname = "form" +ch;
        var start = "<div class=\'" + formname + "'>";
        var middle = {{ formname.as_p }}
        var end = "</div>";
        divForForms.innerHTML =  divForForms.innerHTML + start + middle + end;
        console.log("div created: ", divForForms.innerHTML);
    }

}
```

I have also tried:

```
var middle = "{{ formname.as_p }}"
```

Or:

```
var middel = "{{ formname.as_p | escapejs }}"
```

But nothing seems to be working. I eventually want the div to get roughly created as:

```
<div class="form1">
<input id="id_form1-descr" name="form1-descr" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Edit:
Adding the console output below to show that the form tag is not working inside div's innerHTML. It gives the below error in the javascript console / sources tab:

```
var middle = <input id="id_form1-descr" name="form1-descr" type="hidden" />
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < 
var finish = "</div>";
```

I tried using the form tag within quotes, but that didn't help either.
Help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: What is the console.log() output?

Comment: Hi @fluffels , I have edited my question above, to add the console output at the end. Appreciate your help! Thanks.

Comment: What is the console output if you put {{ formname.as_p }} in quotes?